# Fantasy book about high elf lord, human woman, magic

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read last year a book about a high lord elf whose job is performing magic; he loves books and is looking for old books containing old magic, so called sexual magic.

He finds an intelligent, beautiful human woman and falls for her, but he uses her in order to perform the magic. She solves the mystery of fertility for the elvin population; it is to not perform magic for a month.  This secret was lost by the priests, although the hero's father knew it but, because he hated his son, he never told him.

The hero is elected emperor, after intense adventures and his human wife, pregnant, becomes empress. The society in which they live is composed of humans, who are the lowest socially, and different mixes of elves/humans. Pretty good book.

I can't remember the title or author; thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you remember the color of the book? Was it hard-back?

Comment: I read it in ebook format.

Comment: :p I was hoping the opposite! We can add this to the list of reasons why one should only buy books in paper: So as to facilitate for future searches in identities of written material.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its *[The Use](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15814073-the-use)* (Changing Magic #1) by D.L Carter.

> In an Empire where Earth, Air, Fire and Water Magic is taken for granted. . .The Magic Users of the High Court Elves are suffering a mysterious decrease in fertility. Soon there may not be enough Magicians to support an Empire dependent on Magic for clean water, for weather stability. . . for. . . everything!. While exploring a neglected library Eioth, Magician of All Elements, discovers a book describing the almost unknown practice of Sex Magic! As any respectable magician cannot ignore new knowledge he must explore this branch.
>   First, the book instructs, he needs one special woman.

[image]

Comment: @BMWurm I added the summary. It even looks correct :)

Comment: Thank you so vert much! I raked my brain desperately for anything helpful to fibd it, this is the book :)

Comment: Very happy right now, many thanks.

Comment: Youre welcome. Happy to help :)